# Voltage Drop between W1 and Rc wires

Tags: wiring, heating, thermostat, low-voltage

I recently converted from Oil to Gas. One of my zones is no longer working post conversion (it was working, then nothing worked, and then after they replaced a defective unit on the boiler it didn't work but other zones worked). The plumber said it's most likely the wire between thermostat and the and the system. Here's a picture of what the thermostat set up is:

[image: Nest set up]

Using a voltmeter I can measure ~28V between Rc and G and Y1 but only get roughly 16V (slightly under) for W1 and Rc. What could be causing this this voltage drop? On the other two thermostats the Rh and W1 wires read ~28V. Here's what the wiring looks like at the boiler for that zone:

[image]

You can see that there's an extra wire that's covered in tape that's coincidentally very close in color to the W1 wire. It's also the only zone that has that extra wire. All other zone do not. When I do a volt reading between the blue and yellow capped wires in the picture, I get ~28V when the thermastat says heat. When I do it between the taped and the yellow I get roughly ~58V. What is that wire? Should I wire it in? Is it part of the problem?

Edit more picture based on question below:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You're going to have to provide us with a detailed schematic of the control wiring for the system.  Is there a zone controller involved, or is the system simply using zone valves?  It's possible that the boiler control system is using a different transformer.  Without knowing a lot more about the system, there's no way we can answer definitively.

Comment: I added more pictures. I'm assuming the "zone controller" is the green "zone switching" relay in the pictures. I opened to box and took a picture inside too. The wiring from what I can tell is wires from the thermastats go to the basement and then get wire capped to another wire that go down to the controller. Except for that zone which has that extra uncapped wire that I don't know where it's from or where it goes.

Its possible there's a second transformer for the boiler. How would find out? What other information would help?

Comment: Great, thanks. Now... The wire that's connected to the `Rc` terminal on the thermostat, does that come from the boiler zone controller, or the A/C air handler?

Comment: If you have separate heating and cooling systems (like it appears you do), there should be two `R` wires.  `Rc` which is power from the A/C control transformer, and `Rh` which is power from the heating system control transformer (in your case the zone controller transformer).

Comment: I believe it comes from the AC air handler because when they were doing the switch over, that was the only Nest that didn't lose power and could still trigger the AC (located outside). If I unplug my AC air handler, that should report 0 voltage, right? I don't think there was ever an Rh wire.

Comment: Other than the boiler fuel, what else was changed?

Comment: The whole system was changed. They took out the oil tank, boiler and the hot water heater and put a new boiler, water tank, and the zone controller

Comment: To clarify, the AC system was not changed.

Comment: Where do the red wires (`R`) from the zone controller go?  Seems to me, they should go to `Rh` on the thermostats.

Comment: The red and white wire from the zone controller go about 5 feet off the ground to picture 2 above. The red is then wire capped to a black wire. The white wire is wire capped to a brown wire. There's also a yellow wire that is not hooked up to the controller. The black, the brown and the yellow wire are all bundled together and go into the wall.

Comment: Okay... Can we assume that the brown wire is the same brown wire connected to `W1` on the thermostat, and that there's a black wire tucked back behind the thermostat? If so, it might be as easy as connecting the black wire to `Rh`.

Comment: Hmm worth a look. I'll pull out the thermastat and see if it's there. Though I didn't change the wiring of it since it was oil and the oil burner triggered w/o that black wire being hooked up.

Comment: So you were right. There are actually two black wires there and they were connected to each other. When I disconnected them, one had 0V and one had ~15V. I tried both in Rh and it got the nest to say it's not detecting power. And now it's saying it's not detecting power in the original configuration either to the Rc wire (even though I still see 24V from Rc)

Comment: 0V and 15V between the black wire and what else?  It may be time to call the pros back, as it sounds like you may need somebody who can actually be there.  It's quite difficult to tell you how to wire it, without being able to investigate myself.

Comment: Between the black wire and the W1 wire. You might be right about the pros.